# 2 button accessing different method in the same controller with the same route using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, parameter-passing, eloquent

I have 2 buttons in my blade. I want to update the same database column with them, when I click button 1, it updates the column to 1, when I click the second button it updates the column to 2. I am using the same route to do this because I have to pass the "id" from the view to the controller.

buttons in the view:

```
  {!! Form::open(['method' => 'GET', 'route' => ['show.approve_notification_application', $userdetail->id], 'style'=>'display:inline']) !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Accpet', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) !!}
  {!! Form::close() !!}

  {!! Form::open(['method' => 'GET', 'route' => ['show.approve_notification_application', $userdetail->id], 'style'=>'display:inline']) !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Send to Super Admin', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) !!}
  {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Routes

```
Route::get('/notification_list/notification_application/{notification_id}', 'AdminController@approveNotification')->name('show.approve_notification_application');

Route::get('/notification_list/notification_application/{notification_id}', 'AdminController@sendNotificationToSuperAdmin')->name('show.approve_notification_application');
```

Controller

```
public function approveNotification($id){

        $notification = Notification::find($id);
        $notification->approved = '2';
        $notification->save();

        return redirect()->route('admin.notification_list');
    }


    public function sendNotificationToSuperAdmin($id){

        $notification = Notification::find($id);
        $notification->approved = '1';
        $notification->save();

        return redirect()->route('admin.notification_list');
    }
```

I don't know how to do this. When I click any button, only the second route seems to work which means irrespective of which button I click, it always updates the table to with the value 1.

Comment: Hi Mill3r. When a question is resolved, clicking the tick mark is sufficient - we not use the [solved] device here, and I've removed this from your questions previously. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you can't set two or more routes with same URL and method type. you can use same URL with other type like `Route:get('hi')` and `Route::post('hi')`.

Back to your problem you can do something like this:

**Buttons**

```
 {!! Form::open(['method' => 'GET', 'route' => ['show.approve_notification_application', $userdetail->id], 'style'=>'display:inline']) !!}
{!! Form::hidden('type', 0) !!}
{!! Form::submit('Accpet', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}

{!! Form::open(['method' => 'GET', 'route' => ['show.approve_notification_application', $userdetail->id], 'style'=>'display:inline']) !!}
{!! Form::hidden('type', 1) !!}
{!! Form::submit('Send to Super Admin', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Controller**

```
public function approveNotification(Request $request, $id){

    $notification = Notification::find($id);
    $notification->approved = $request->input('type') == 1 ? 1 : 2;
    $notification->save();

    return redirect()->route('admin.notification_list');
}
```

don't forget to insert `use Illuminate\Http\Request` in the top of the file after namespace.

**Routes**

keep the first and delete the second one.

Comment: change method from **get** to **post** also in the route - or - change `$request->input('type')` to `$request->get('type')` **I prefared first**

Comment: one out of topic question. i know `1 ? 1 : 2` is a if else statement. but can you please tell me how to read this if else?

Comment: if $request->input('type') === 1 { $notification->approved = 1 } else { $notification->approved = 2 }

Answer (score 1):

**The reason to your problem :**

in the routes file - you called 2 methods with the same name - thats why it arrive to the 2nd route ( the seconed name overwrite the first one );

**How to solve it ?**

First - delete one of the routes.

Then - add an hidden field in your form, so you can know later which button was clicked

After that - you will need to add  an IF in your controller - according to $id
something like this :

```
if ($yourHiddenField == 1) {
   ... your code here...
} elseif ($yourHiddenField == 2 ) {
   ... your code here ...
}
```

( you will need to get the value of the hidden field first )

Comment: the id is same in my case. Its the user id. One button is for accepting the application another for send it for further approval. 
how do i use the if else statement to select between the 2 buttons?

Comment: you will need to add hidden field in your forms - in the first one you will put value="1" , and in the seconed you will set value="2" .  I updated my answer according this